# How to use a function inside a custom jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

couldn't find a specific answer.

If I create a jQuery function, call it "doMobile" per say, and I want it to use a function inside of it if so, what do I do?

This is what I am trying to do:

```
$.fn.doMobile = function(somefunctioninside) {
  if ( $('.mobile').is(':visible') )
     somefunctioninside();
};

$('.menu').doMobile(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

When I it like that though, $(this) - $('.menu) doesn't becomes red.

Comment: @Cerbrus, the question you marked as duplicated is not the good one. The linked question doesn't use jQuery, which is crucial here since the OP want to use `this` as an HTML element. Im sure there is a duplicated somewhere, but it isn't this one (or there is a better one).

Comment: The question is about how to call `somefunctioninside`. The linked question explains exactly that.

Comment: @Cerbrus I agreed, but the answer will not solve the OP problem. He will, after reading it, ask "How to make `this` the HTML element?"

Comment: It does answer the question the OP is asking here, however.

Comment: @Cerbrus hence why should suggest the OP to modify his question before closing it because you know the linked answer *answer* the question but his code will not work...

Comment: I don't think the question will be reopened matt, so here your answer. In your case, you want to use this : `this.each(somefunctioninside)`, but you could also use `somefunctioninside.call(this);`. The second one is different though, `this` will not be an HTML element, but a jQuery object, so don't need to wrap it inside a `$()`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon this.each(somefunctioninside) is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$.fn.doMobile = function (someFunction) {
    someFunction.call(this);
};

$('.menu').doMobile(test);

function test() {
   this.css('background-color', 'green');
    alert("came");
}
```

pass `this` reference . @Karl-AndréGagnon told like this way

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9sPw6/4/)

Comment: I need $(this).css('background-color', 'red') to be inside test(). Im going to use this function multiple times to check if the document is watched on mobile devices and effect elements if so.

Comment: @matt4692 to check updated post to use conman by passing a reference

Comment: $('.menu').doMobile(test,test1,test2); you can pass more function

Comment: is that the best way to do it? I mean, when I use .click(function() ... I don't need to specify an element like you do with "elem". Is there a way around it?

Comment: @matt4692 can't post an answer, so i've commented on your question on how to do it.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Got it! this.each worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon thanks for given such valuable things ..i implemented your option